# Database design with creating a product that has two prices

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm creating a database design for our water refilling system and I'm just new to databases. I am stuck with creating table that provides two different prices for a product. To further explain my problem, here's an example, a product's ('5 GALLON') price changes when it is delivered or bought on point by a customer. For example a delivered ('5 GALLON') is 45 pesos while a bought on point gallon is only 40 pesos. Can someone help me please?

Here's my codes so far

```
create table Product (
    product_id int primary key,
    prodtype_id int,
    product_name varchar(55),
    product_quantity int
)

-----NOT SURE IF THESE TWO TABLES ARE CORRECT
create table DeliveryPrice (
    prod_id int,
    product_price money,
    foreign key (prod_id) references Product
)

create table OnPointPrice(
    prod_id int,
    product_price money,
    foreign key (prod_id) references Product
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely better off just having the two prices in the `Product` table. They are attributes of the product, so that's where they belong.

Also, you should specify which columns are `NOT NULL` in your database (which should be most of them).

Comment: So what happens if I want to add that selected product price to a Line and Invoice that the Customer picked whether its delivery or onsite?

Comment: You have two choices. You can have a flag for "delivered" or "picked up" on the line item (or entire invoice), or you can have a single price for the product, but consider "delivered" and "picked up" as two different products, just as you would 5 gals. of water vs. 10 gals. of water.

Answer (score 0):

So is this correct?

create table Product(
product_id int primary key,
product_name varchar(55) not null,
product_quantity int not null,
pickup_price money not null,
delivery_price money not null
)

create table Customer(
customer_id int primary key,
customer_name varchar (255) not null,
customer_address varchar(200),
customer_phone int 
)
create table INVOICE(
inv_number int primary key,
customer_id varchar(5),
foreign key (customer_id) references Customer,
inv_date date not null,
bought_mode char(10) not null
)

create table LINE(
INV_NUMBER int,
foreign key (INV_NUMBER) references INVOICE,
LINE_NUMBER INT not null,
PRIMARY KEY (INV_NUMBER, LINE_NUMBER),
line_quantity int not null,
line_price money not null
)